# How can I align Bootstrap Carousel indicator icons and arrow controls on the same line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I use this carousel and love it:
https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135508#html-tab-view

The only thing is, I want the control to be **around the indicators**.

Currently, it's like this:

```
                  <            >
   SLIDE               SLIDE              SLIDE
                        ...
```

**What I want:**

```
   SLIDE               SLIDE              SLIDE
                 <      ...     >
```

already tried:

```
<!--Controls-->
<div class="controls-top">
    <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
<!--/.Controls-->
```

Anyone knows how I can achieve this with bootstrap classes without any wild css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the enclosing div of the carousel to a `flex`, changing the flex-order, and managing the extra margins did it.

The code becomes:

```
<div id="multi-item-example" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="controls-top order-1 d-flex">
        <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>

        <ol class="carousel-indicators my-0 mx-5 position-relative d-flex align-items-center">
            <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active m-0 mr-2"></li>
            <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="1" class="m-0 mr-2"></li>
            <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="2" class="m-0 mr-2"></li>
        </ol>

        <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        // carousel images and stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Refer here:
[Snippet](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/3549496)